# How to map "Google Storage for Developers" as a drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, cloud-storage

I just got access to a nice "Google Storage for Developers"-account which I'd like to use as a backup-drive with Windows.

Gladinet Cloud Desktop offers this functionality, but their implementation doesn't seem to work. Are there any other alternatives available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently cannot mount it natively as if it were a local directory. If you want to backup your files, I suggest you use another service like [DropBox](http://dropbox.com).